# Get height of an element in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

I'm trying to 'slide toggle' an element using Angular 2 Animations.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Dof60vwHp79eiThhj9vW?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.scss'],
  animations: [
      trigger('toggleHeight', [
          state('inactive', style({
            height: '0',
          })),
          state('active', style({
              height: '100%' //this.el.nativeElement.scrollHeight + 'px'
          })),
          transition('inactive => active', animate('300ms ease-in')),
          transition('active => inactive', animate('300ms ease-out'))
      ])
  ]
})
```

Above code works but I can't exactly see the transition of the height. I know it's not possible to animate a 'height' property with 'auto' value in CSS.

In order to auto generate the height, Is it possible to make it something like,

```
state('active', style({
   height: this.nativeElement.height + 'px'
})),
```

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work AFAIK.

```
 height: '*'
```

Just checked. It works !

You can read more here : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html#!#automatic-property-calculation